# Heroku deployment of Python app unsuccessful but works locally?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

[Code here](https://github.com/applephil/headlyne).

This app used to work, both on Heroku and locally on my computer. It gets the top headlines from r/worldnews, puts its through a geography API, matches to Google Geocoding API, and then pins it on a rendered 3D globe.

Recently it stopped working (Internal Server Error message) on the heroku page, so I've been trying to figure out why– but the strange part is it only fails on Heroku and not locally. Below is the log with no apparent error but stops short after a couple calls:

```
2015-05-01T05:26:18.554846+00:00 app[web.1]: 26
2015-05-01T05:26:18.891621+00:00 app[web.1]: Pacific Ocean
2015-05-01T05:26:18.891614+00:00 app[web.1]: Error in entity extraction call:  cannot-retrieve:downstream-http-error:0
2015-05-01T05:26:18.920050+00:00 app[web.1]: [-8.783195, -124.508523]
2015-05-01T05:26:19.543681+00:00 app[web.1]: Paraguay
2015-05-01T05:26:19.605605+00:00 app[web.1]: [-23.442503, -58.443832]
2015-05-01T05:26:20.122190+00:00 app[web.1]: China
2015-05-01T05:26:20.151125+00:00 app[web.1]: [35.86166, 104.195397]
2015-05-01T05:26:20.559544+00:00 app[web.1]: North Korea
2015-05-01T05:26:20.589243+00:00 app[web.1]: [40.339852, 127.510093]
2015-05-01T05:26:21.026208+00:00 app[web.1]: United States
2015-05-01T05:26:21.053852+00:00 app[web.1]: [37.09024, -95.712891]
2015-05-01T05:26:21.832992+00:00 app[web.1]: Florence
2015-05-01T05:26:21.874261+00:00 app[web.1]: [43.7695604, 11.2558136]
2015-05-01T05:26:22.623761+00:00 app[web.1]: Japan
2015-05-01T05:26:22.651791+00:00 app[web.1]: [36.204824, 138.252924]
2015-05-01T05:26:23.226770+00:00 app[web.1]: Canada
2015-05-01T05:26:23.254924+00:00 app[web.1]: [56.130366, -106.346771]
2015-05-01T05:26:24.062596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=headlyne.herokuapp.com request_id=da61bd71-3eae-4cf9-af20-d0d46a06f6b5 fwd="73.170.254.78" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7086ms status=500 bytes=456
```

I've been trying to investigate reasons why, but nothing seems to work. Why is it failing only on the Heroku deployment when it used to work there before?

Comment: Your code is running, but it failed at https://github.com/applephil/headlyne/blob/master/headline.py#L70 , looks like you are not able to access `AlchemyAPI` on heroku

Comment: Thanks @number5. I've programmed it to ignore that warning (just output it and move on)... it works locally. =(